# addEventListener not working in script tag - Static Resources Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, js, recaptcha

We are trying to implement recaptcha. We are using static resources for recaptcha events instead of writing those in the head markup.

We have the following function in lwc:

```
@api
verify(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    document.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent("grecaptchaExecute")
    );
}
```

This event is getting fired but we have the event listener in static resources but that isn't getting executed.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<my_site_key>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('In this DOMContentLoaded')
document.addEventListener('grecaptchaExecute', function(e) {
    console.log('In grecaptchaExecute')
    grecaptcha.execute('<my_site_key>').then(function(token) {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('grecaptchaVerified', {'detail': {response: token}}));
    });
}); </script>
```

Can someone please help with this issue?

Comment: Please check this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369770/new-to-lwc-trying-to-implement-google-recaptcha-and-am-struggling-to-figure-o

Comment: @SarojBera this event listener is not working, I haven't used "this" in the event listener. console inside the function itself isn't getting printed.